# POST random number field generated at the client onsubmit

Tags: php, javascript, post

I have a simple javascript:

```
function myfunction(form)
```

and a form with submit button:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="return myfunction(this)" onsubmit="return myfunction(this)" value="Send!">
```

So when the user sends the form, the function is called.
In this function, for example I want to create a random number, and POST that as well with the information I have in the form.

So in the php file I read the data I want to say

```
$randomNumberGeneratedInTheScript = $_POST['randomNumber'];
```

Is this possible?
Thanks..

( I do not want to generate the random number in the php file. It has to be done in JavaScript. )

Comment: What are you trying to do with the random number? What's it's function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple. Use a hidden form field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="randomNumber" value="">
```

Then you can use the [math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) function to produce a random number

```
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
```

*Note: that will produce a number bettween 1 and 1000, change the 1000 to any value you wish*

Then onload or in a separate function you can call this and set the value of the hidden field

```
    document.getElementById('randomID').value = randomNumber;
```

There are other methods of doing it, but for the situation you described this sounds like the most cross compatible and easiest method to use.

Comment: Thanks, I made this work. Actually I was wondering if I can simply POST in the javascript but I guess it is not possible.. Nice trick, thanks.

Comment: There are some hacks which allow you to do that, but it's really not pretty or IE friendly!

Comment: @KorayTugay - [Another method](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/S94BW/), no `onsubmit`, and note I include a `-1` (and you would change that to `type="hidden" I assume), so you can detect and manage if the random script doesn't run properly before submitting.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden input in the form called randomNumber. In myFunction generate the random number and set the hidden input value to be the random number. Onsubmit can now call the function first, then submit the form normally.

Comment: Can you elobrate sir please?

Comment: Sure. I would follow the example that tim.baker offered. But if you want the random number to be generated when the form is submitted, you can will have to do one thing different from his solution. In your submit button, get rid of onClick. Then change onSubmit to be onsubmit="generateRandomNumber()" where  generateRandomNumber is a function as descripbed by tim.baker. Since the onClick is not returning anything, the function will be called, then submitted with the random number in the hidden field.